# Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit - Unmet Dependencies (skype, steam, samba)

Tags: apt

I can't install many different kinds of packages on my Ubuntu 14.04 64bit system.

I have run the command

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

as many of the related questions have suggested, but when I run

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Steam fails too:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Also, even something I thought was simple like samba fails to install:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 samba : Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.1 is to be installed
         Depends: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.1 is to be installed
         Depends: samba-dsdb-modules but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.1 is to be installed
         Recommends: attr
         Recommends: samba-vfs-modules but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here are the uncommented lines from `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

I believe this has something to do with the "new" (?) multiarch system in Ubuntu 14.04 (my last system ran 13.04), but I don't really know what to do to fix this problem.  I have seen many suggests that involve crowbaring packages from older distributions into 14.04, but I don't want to do that unless as a last resort.

The only PPA I have installed is the one for Google Chrome.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It's not multiarch. Multiarch has been present since 12.10.

Comment: Did you have trusty-updates enabled at any point? It doesn't look like `trusty-updates` is present in your `sources.list`, but the `samba` package is from `trusty-updates`.

Comment: choose a different download server.

Comment: I've seen that possible duplicate and chose to create my own because most users seem to get this working without resorting to manually downloading packages.  Also, my issue with `samba` seems to suggest deeper problems.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - I changed from "Main Server" to "Server for United States" (my country), and had no effect

Comment: post the output of `cat /var/lib/dpkg/arch`. Did you update all the repositories by running `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get check`, `sudo dpkg -C`?

Comment: @user292735: Try enabling `trusty-updates`, update, and redownload.

Answer (score 0):

For Skype and Steam, the packages come from the Canonical partner's repo, for which the correct line is:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

There's an `ubuntu` at the end of the URL, missing in your list.

Try again after an `apt-get update` after making this change. You should use the  `software-properties-gtk` program for selecting from such pre-listed repositories. You can run it by typing `Sources` in the Dash.

I'm not sure of `samba`. In this case, the error is that you have held broken packages. I suggest an `apt-get install -f`.

Comment: I had it with the `ubuntu` before, but I saw a tip that had it removed.  I added it back to no effect.

Running `apt-get install -f` does nothing:
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: @user292735 Worst case: get the package of samba/skype/steam, install it using `dpkg` and then do `apt-get install -f`: `apt-get download skype; sudo dpkg -i skype*.deb; sudo apt-get install -f`
Presumably the problem only occurs when you try to install these packages, so forcing an install and then getting apt-get to fix things might work, but this is a **dangerous** way.

Comment: Isn't there something wrong with my package system though?  I saw lots of users claim `skype` "just worked" for them.

Also, the fact that something like `samba` doesn't install really worries me.

I was hoping to treat the cause, not the symptoms here.

Comment: @user292735, yes, I'd say there is. I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 the day after it released, and it's having no trouble installing these packages. Nor am I having trouble with a fresh installation. I think you might have to use `synaptic` to see where exactly the problem might be.

Comment: @user292735, for that matter, I didn't even need to run the add-architectures command.

Comment: Synaptic gives me the same error when I try to install `samba`

Comment: @user292735, only for `samba` or the others as well?

Comment: Aha.  For `skype`, it says it will remove lots of irrelevant packages like `dconf-editor`, `google-chrome-stable`, and `vlc`

Comment: @user292735 Is this package hangover from 13.04? Perhaps some package from that time still hanging aroung, satisfying dependencies and screwing up things? Are there any local or auto-removable packages in Synaptic?

Comment: This system was a clean install of 14.04.  I don't trust upgrades for this very reason.  I don't know how to do an autoremove from synaptic, but `sudo apt-get autoremove` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @user292735, here's my sources.list: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7631468/. Replace the IITK mirror url with us.archive.ubuntu.com and try.

Comment: Your repositories worked.  Would you like to submit that as the answer so I can mark it?  What happened to cause the problem?

Comment: @user292735 My best guess is the comment from saiarcot895 on the question: the trusty-updates repositories weren't all enabled. Did you use the IITK urls or archive.ubuntu.com ones? Can you check with the latter if you haven't, and see if a reinstall proceeds fine?